# How to restructure dataframe using a LOOP

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I posted this question in a diff senario and now I would like to know how to do it using a loop. For larger dataframes where i have say 100 columns it becomes difficult to manually concatenate.

I have this Pandas DataFrame:

```
data4 = {'g_pairs':['an_jk', 'tf_ha', 'ab_rh', 'et_x2','yr_po'],
         'g_a':['en762','en72b','en925','en980','en009'],
         'g_b':['en361','en231','en666','en771','en909'],
         'epi|ap':[0.020,1,0.05,0.7,0.001],
         'ap|epi':[1,1,0.1,0.0001,1],
         'fib|mac':[0.001,0.002,0.0021,0.3,0.005],
         'mac|fib':[0.0002,0.0043,0.0067,0.0123,0.0110]}
 
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)
```

```
   g_pairs  g_a     g_b    epi|ap   ap|epi  fib|mac mac|fib
0   an_jk   en762   en361   0.020   1.0000  0.0010  0.0002
1   tf_ha   en72b   en231   1.000   1.0000  0.0020  0.0043
2   ab_rh   en925   en666   0.050   0.1000  0.0021  0.0067
3   et_x2   en980   en771   0.700   0.0001  0.3000  0.0123
4   yr_po   en009   en909   0.001   1.0000  0.0050  0.0110
```

I would like to restructure the table by repositioning column name opposites. For example, an_jk has a value of 1 under ap|epi, but if I flip the name to jk_an I can add that new item under the epi|ap column and get rid of the ap|epi column.

In essence,I would like to define a list with all names and have the loop iterate through this the list to generate this table.

```
list = ['ap','epi','fib','mac']

for i in range(0,len(list)):
     for j in range(i, len(list)):
         col = list[i]+'|'+list[j]
         col2 = list[j]+'|'+list[i]
```

something somewhat to that effect.

Output should look like this:

```
 g_pairs  g_a     g_b     epi|ap  fib|mac
0   an_jk   en762   en361   0.0200  0.0010
1   jk_an   en762   en361   1.0000  0.0002
2   tf_ha   en72b   en231   1.0000  0.0020
3   ha_tf   en72b   en231   1.0000  0.0043
4   ab_rh   en925   en666   0.0500  0.0021
5   rh_ab   en925   en666   0.1000  0.0067
6   et_x2   en980   en771   0.7000  0.3000
7   x2_et   en980   en771   0.0001  0.0123
8   yr_po   en009   en909   0.0010  0.0050
9   po_yr   en009   en909   1.0000  0.0110
```

Comment: This can be done without a loop. A good practice is always not to use a loop in `Pandas`. A question for you is indexing important?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution without for loop to create the df , I only use for loop to change the column name which will be really fast.

```
df.columns = ['|'.join(sorted(x.split('|'))) if '|' in x else x for x in df.columns]
df = df.set_index(['g_pairs','g_a','g_b'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns,df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).cumcount()])
out = df.stack().reset_index()
g_pairs    g_a    g_b  level_3  ap|epi  fib|mac
0   an_jk  en762  en361        0  0.0200   0.0010
1   an_jk  en762  en361        1  1.0000   0.0002
2   tf_ha  en72b  en231        0  1.0000   0.0020
3   tf_ha  en72b  en231        1  1.0000   0.0043
4   ab_rh  en925  en666        0  0.0500   0.0021
5   ab_rh  en925  en666        1  0.1000   0.0067
6   et_x2  en980  en771        0  0.7000   0.3000
7   et_x2  en980  en771        1  0.0001   0.0123
8   yr_po  en009  en909        0  0.0010   0.0050
9   yr_po  en009  en909        1  1.0000   0.0110
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to reshape the data; this works best if your column is ordered, and you know the names of the new columns:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
outcome = df4.pivot_longer(index = slice('g_pairs', 'g_b'), # or index = 'g*', 
                           names_to=['epi|ap', 'fib|mac'], 
                           names_pattern=['ap', 'fib'],  
                           sort_by_appearance=True)

print(outcome)

  g_pairs    g_a    g_b  epi|ap  fib|mac
0   an_jk  en762  en361  0.0200   0.0010
1   an_jk  en762  en361  1.0000   0.0002
2   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0020
3   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0043
4   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.0500   0.0021
5   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.1000   0.0067
6   et_x2  en980  en771  0.7000   0.3000
7   et_x2  en980  en771  0.0001   0.0123
8   yr_po  en009  en909  0.0010   0.0050
9   yr_po  en009  en909  1.0000   0.0110
```

You can avoid `pivot_longer` and build up the reshaping process (with the idea from @BENY's solution):

```py
outcome = df4.set_index(['g_pairs', 'g_a', 'g_b'])
# this results in duplicated columns
cols = outcome.columns.str.split('|', expand = True).map(sorted).map(tuple) 
# the counter allows us to create unique columns,
# via MultiIndex
counter = pd.Series(cols.get_level_values(0)).groupby(cols).cumcount()
outcome.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([cols.map("|".join), counter])
(outcome.stack(level = -1)
        .droplevel(-1)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"ap|epi":"epi|ap"})
)

  g_pairs    g_a    g_b  ep|api  fib|mac
0   an_jk  en762  en361  0.0200   0.0010
1   an_jk  en762  en361  1.0000   0.0002
2   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0020
3   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0043
4   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.0500   0.0021
5   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.1000   0.0067
6   et_x2  en980  en771  0.7000   0.3000
7   et_x2  en980  en771  0.0001   0.0123
8   yr_po  en009  en909  0.0010   0.0050
9   yr_po  en009  en909  1.0000   0.0110
```

This works as long as the index is unique; `pivot_longer` covers scenarios where index may not be unique.

To go further and flip the values in `g_pairs`, we can leverage `str.replace` after a `groupby` with `cumcount`:

First, groupby to get the cumulative count:

```py
 outcome['counter'] = outcome.groupby('g_pairs').cumcount()
print(outcome)
g_pairs    g_a    g_b  epi|ap  fib|mac  counter
0   an_jk  en762  en361  0.0200   0.0010        0
1   an_jk  en762  en361  1.0000   0.0002        1
2   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0020        0
3   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0043        1
4   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.0500   0.0021        0
5   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.1000   0.0067        1
6   et_x2  en980  en771  0.7000   0.3000        0
7   et_x2  en980  en771  0.0001   0.0123        1
8   yr_po  en009  en909  0.0010   0.0050        0
9   yr_po  en009  en909  1.0000   0.0110        1
```

Next, use `pd.str.replace` to flip the text if counter is equal to 1:

```py
pat = r"(?P<first>.+)_(?P<last>.+)"

repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('last')}_{m.group('first')}"

 outcome['g_pairs'] = outcome.g_pairs.where(outcome.counter.eq(0), 
                                           outcome.g_pairs
                                                 .str.replace(pat, 
                                                              repl, 
                                                              regex = True)
                                           )

 outcome.drop(columns='counter')

  g_pairs    g_a    g_b  epi|ap  fib|mac
0   an_jk  en762  en361  0.0200   0.0010
1   jk_an  en762  en361  1.0000   0.0002
2   tf_ha  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0020
3   ha_tf  en72b  en231  1.0000   0.0043
4   ab_rh  en925  en666  0.0500   0.0021
5   rh_ab  en925  en666  0.1000   0.0067
6   et_x2  en980  en771  0.7000   0.3000
7   x2_et  en980  en771  0.0001   0.0123
8   yr_po  en009  en909  0.0010   0.0050
9   po_yr  en009  en909  1.0000   0.0110
```

Comment: Pretty cool answers, but this process becomes tedious with larger dataframes. I have a dataframes that has over 100 columns that I would like to apply this process too. That's why I wanna learn how to use a loop to perform this task. I can't realistically do it manually.

Comment: with a loop, it likely would be pretty slow. probably think of another way of looping over only the columns and use vectorised options for the body of the dataframe. Another option would be to loop through the columns, split, sort, get the unique columns, keep the unique columns as your new column names, and then apply pandas vectorised methods to the body. more efficient that way. a 1000 columns is a lot though, I feel it would be hard to confirm your output is right